# Unable to find difference between list and tuple

Tags: python-3.x

Dear public recently I have been receiving an unusual error to do with tuples. I think it has something to do with the spaces. Thanks for the help Adam FYI this program generates all combination and puts numbers together.

Does anybody know whats going on

```
import intercools 
list1 = []
stuff = [1, 2, 3]
for L in range(0, len(stuff+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
         list1.append(subset) 
print(list1) 
sep = [map(str,l)for l in list1]
nl = [int(''.join(s)) for s in sep]
print(nl)
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to ask us?

Comment: Sorry totally forgot to ask

Comment: *"I have been receiving an unusual error"* What error?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of syntax errors present in your code. To start,

- Your outer loop is missing an right parenthesis after `stuff`
- The name of the module is `itertools` not `intercools`

After getting through those,

```
nl = [int(''.join(s)) for s in sep]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So it appears that `sep` is occasionally empty. It's not clear what your goal is, but it looks like `list1` does not contain what you expect.